# How to configure Sublime Text 2 editor for easier working with ATK4 framework?

Tags: sublimetext2, atk4

How to configure Sublime Text 2 editor for easier working with ATK4 framework?

I'm interested in some standard macros (snippets) for page, view, model files and maybe some more Sublime Text 2 editor configuration details useful for developing in ATK4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had two and I've contributed them into atk4/tools folder. You can found them here:

https://github.com/atk4/atk4/tree/master/tools

Feel free to contribute more!

Answer (score 0):

I cannot find any plugins for ATK4. You could make requests for plugins on the [ST2 UserEcho](http://sublimetext.userecho.com/) and see if you get any bites.